# Trying to compile some code for my python game, but i get this error.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, macos, pip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/game.py", line 2, in 
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I successfully installed and upgrade the pip in the mac terminal to pip vervion 19.3.1. However when I went back to my code and recompiled it and I still got the same error message. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'.

I running macOS Catalina, version 10.15.1. And python version 3.8.0.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
alex@Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % pip install --upgrade pip --user
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
alex@Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % pip3 install --upgrade pip --user
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
alex@Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ %

```
import math
import pygame

# Define some colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# Size of break-out blocks
block_width = 23
block_height = 15


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """This class represents each block that will get knocked out by the ball
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame """

    def __init__(self, color, x, y):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
            and its x and y position. """

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create the image of the block of appropriate size
        # The width and height are sent as a list for the first parameter.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([block_width, block_height])

        # Fill the image with the appropriate color
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Move the top left of the rectangle to x,y.
        # This is where our block will appear..
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the ball
        It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame """

    # Speed in pixels per cycle
    speed = 10.0

    # Floating point representation of where the ball is
    x = 0.0
    y = 180.0

    # Direction of ball (in degrees)
    direction = 200

    width = 10
    height = 10

    # Constructor. Pass in the color of the block, and its x and y position
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create the image of the ball
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])

        # Color the ball
        self.image.fill(white)

        # Get a rectangle object that shows where our image is
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Get attributes for the height/width of the screen
        self.screenheight = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()
        self.screenwidth = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()

    def bounce(self, diff):
        """ This function will bounce the ball
            off a horizontal surface (not a vertical one) """

        self.direction = (180 - self.direction) % 360
        self.direction -= diff

    def update(self):
        """ Update the position of the ball. """
        # Sine and Cosine work in degrees, so we have to convert them
        direction_radians = math.radians(self.direction)

        # Change the position (x and y) according to the speed and direction
        self.x += self.speed * math.sin(direction_radians)
        self.y -= self.speed * math.cos(direction_radians)

        # Move the image to where our x and y are
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y

        # Do we bounce off the top of the screen?
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.bounce(0)
            self.y = 1

        # Do we bounce off the left of the screen?
        if self.x <= 0:
            self.direction = (360 - self.direction) % 360
            self.x = 1

        # Do we bounce of the right side of the screen?
        if self.x > self.screenwidth - self.width:
            self.direction = (360 - self.direction) % 360
            self.x = self.screenwidth - self.width - 1

        # Did we fall off the bottom edge of the screen?
        if self.y > 600:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bar at the bottom that the
    player controls. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor for Player. """
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.width = 75
        self.height = 15
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
        self.image.fill((white))

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screenheight = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()
        self.screenwidth = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()

        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = self.screenheight-self.height

    def update(self):
        """ Update the player position. """
        # Get where the mouse is
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # Set the left side of the player bar to the mouse position
        self.rect.x = pos[0]
        # Make sure we don't push the player paddle
        # off the right side of the screen
        if self.rect.x > self.screenwidth - self.width:
            self.rect.x = self.screenwidth - self.width

# Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

# Create an 800x600 sized screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

# Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Breakout')

# Enable this to make the mouse disappear when over our window
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

# This is a font we use to draw text on the screen (size 36)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

# Create a surface we can draw on
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

# Create sprite lists
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Create the player paddle object
player = Player()
allsprites.add(player)

# Create the ball
ball = Ball()
allsprites.add(ball)
balls.add(ball)

# The top of the block (y position)
top = 80

# Number of blocks to create
blockcount = 32

# --- Create blocks

# Five rows of blocks
for row in range(5):
    # 32 columns of blocks
    for column in range(0, blockcount):
        # Create a block (color,x,y)
        block = Block(blue, column * (block_width + 2) + 1, top)
        blocks.add(block)
        allsprites.add(block)
    # Move the top of the next row down
    top += block_height + 2

# Clock to limit speed
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Is the game over?
game_over = False

# Exit the program?
exit_program = False

# Main program loop
while not exit_program:

    # Limit to 30 fps
    clock.tick(30)

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(black)

    # Process the events in the game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit_program = True

    # Update the ball and player position as long
    # as the game is not over.
    if not game_over:
        # Update the player and ball positions
        player.update()
        game_over = ball.update()

    # If we are done, print game over
    if game_over:
        text = font.render("Game Over", True, white)
        textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
        textpos.top = 300
        screen.blit(text, textpos)

    # See if the ball hits the player paddle
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, balls, False):
        # The 'diff' lets you try to bounce the ball left or right
        # depending where on the paddle you hit it
        diff = (player.rect.x + player.width/2) - (ball.rect.x+ball.width/2)

        # Set the ball's y position in case
        # we hit the ball on the edge of the paddle
        ball.rect.y = screen.get_height() - player.rect.height - ball.rect.height - 1
        ball.bounce(diff)

    # Check for collisions between the ball and the blocks
    deadblocks = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, blocks, True)

    # If we actually hit a block, bounce the ball
    if len(deadblocks) > 0:
        ball.bounce(0)

        # Game ends if all the blocks are gone
        if len(blocks) == 0:
            game_over = True

    # Draw Everything
    allsprites.draw(screen)

    # Flip the screen and show what we've drawn
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Have you installed pygame? (what does `pip freeze` give you?) If not, try `pip install --user pygame`

Comment: altgraph==0.10.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
bonjour-py==0.3
cffi==1.12.2
cryptography==2.6.1
enum34==1.1.6
future==0.17.1
ipaddress==1.0.22
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
py2app==0.7.3
pycparser==2.19
pygame==1.9.2

Comment: pip freeze gives me all of those things, including pygame == 1.9.2. But when i go back to the python idle  to compile the code i still get the same error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame

Comment: Your `pip` is obviously from Python 2.7. It installed `pygame` for 2.7 and you tried to use it with Python 3.8. Use `pip` for 3.8. Something like `pip3.8` or `python3.8 -m pip`.